# Error while printing out arraylist elements

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is a small program which adds and print out workers. When calling a method to print I receive an output with identical elements as many times as the number of elements I have added. I cant understand where is my mistake.

```
public class Radnik {
    static List<Radnik> workers = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;


    public static void main (String []args) {
        Radnik.add();
        for(Radnik r : workers) {
            System.out.println(r);
        }
    }
    public static void add () {
        String name;
        String answer;
        do {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("name");
            name = s.next();
            Radnik f = new Radnik();
            workers.add(f);
            System.out.println("More");
            answer = s.next();
        } while (answer.equals("yes"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to add `name` to the `Radnik` instance `f` anywhere, so All Radniks will be identical.

Comment: in the add() method use the variable name=s.next();

Comment: `Radnik` does not have a constructor, fields, or instance methods. It only  makes sense that they are all identical.

Comment: Thank you for reply. How should I do it cause I'm already got confused trying to solve it

Answer (score 3):

You never set the `name` to a `Radnik`.
I would add the constructor `Radnik(String name)` to initialize `name` and also add an getter and setter.

`System.out.println(r)` will only print nonsense because it calls [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--). You have to override `toString()` or call another method to output something meaningful.

---

```
public class Radnik {
    static List<Radnik> workers = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;


    public Radnik(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Radnik=[name=\""+name+"\"]";
    }

    public static void main (String []args) {
        Radnik.add();
        for(Radnik r : workers) {
            System.out.println(r);
        }
    }
    public static void add () {
        String name;
        String answer;
        do{
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("name");
            name = s.next();
            Radnik f = new Radnik(name);
            workers.add(f);
            System.out.println("More");
            answer = s.next();
        } while (answer.equals("yes"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainClass{
    private static List<Radnik> workers = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main (String []args) {
        new MainClass().add();
        for(Radnik r : workers) {
            System.out.println(r.getName());
        }
    }

    public void add () {
        String name;
        String answer;
        do{
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("name");
            name = s.next();
            Radnik f = new Radnik();
            f.setName(name);
            workers.add(f);
            System.out.println("More");
            answer = s.next();
        } while (answer.equals("yes"));
    }

    public class Radnik {

        private String name;

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing it in a wrong way. You should use getter & setter property to get & retrieve value from name variable. This sample should help you.